# python try: except: pass; on multi line try statements

Tags: python, exception

I have a block of statements in a `try: except KeyError: pass` block and wanted to know how I could have Python attempt to execute the code after the line that throws the exception.

For e.g

```
try:
  print "entering try block"
  print this_var_does_not_exists
  print "past exception"
except:
  pass
```

I want to try and print `"past exception"`.

When I run the above code it only prints `'entering try block'`

Comment: Move the print statement to `except` block.

Comment: exception raised means raised...there is no way to do what you want.

Comment: But then it wont execute if the variable does exist. I'm actually parsing an XML file - in some responses certain Key's exist and in others they don't.

Comment: And? It it easy to check whatever condition is necessary without using try..except...your code is appearently broken

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python doesn't allow you to re-enter a failed block. Instead, you can make a nested `try` block:

```
try:
    print "before"
    try:
        print d['not-exist']
    except KeyError:
        pass
    print "after"
except OtherError:
    print "OtherError"
```

Note that you can often avoid `KeyError`s using `.get`:

```
try:
    x = d['key']
except KeyError:
    x = 0
```

is equivalent to

```
x = d.get('key', 0)
```

---

*In general*, try to make your `try` blocks as short as logically possible, so you have a better chance of dealing with the errors in an appropriate, localized fashion.

Comment: Awesome. Thats what I needed! - .get :)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use 'else' to a try/except block:

```
d={'a':1, 'b':2, 'd':4}

for k in 'abcd':
     try:
        print k, d[k],
     except KeyError:
        print '{} not there'.format(k)
     else:
        print 'I did it! Found {}'.format(k)
```

Prints:

```
a 1 I did it! Found a
b 2 I did it! Found b
c c not there
d 4 I did it! Found d
```

In general, the full [try/except/else/final](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) set go like this:

```
try:
    potential_error()
except ExceptionType:
    handle_that_error_somehow()
else:                            # 'else' to the except is SUCCESS
    # There was no error
    # handle success!
    handle_success()
finally:
    # success or failure -- do this
    regardless_something_we_always_need_to_do()
```

Answer (score 4):

python supports `finally` blocks, which will be executed even if there is an exception in the try block:

```
try:
  print "entering try block"
  print this_var_does_not_exists
except:
  pass
finally:
  print "past exception"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with that structure.  You'd need to move the extra `print` out of the `try` block.  The way a try/except block works is that if an exception is raised it jumps to the appropriate `except` block.  There's no way to go back.  If you want to continue, you need to put your code either in the except or a `finally`, or after the whole block.  Here's one example:

```
try:
  print "entering try block"
  print this_var_does_not_exists
finally:
  print "past exception"
```

Also, don't form the dangerous habit of using bare `except:` clauses, especially with `pass` as their only content.  You should catch the kinds of exceptions you can handle, and then handle them, not blindly silence all exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

print with literal string will not raise exception. Put try-except only in the second print statement.

```
print "entering try block"
try:
  print this_var_does_not_exists
except:
    pass
print "past exception"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put it after the try-except block

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine a situation, when indeed it may be useful to execute many such one-line try-excepts without a need to add try-except block each time.

Let's say that you have a dictionary d and an object o. Object has three attributes: 'a', 'b' and 'c'. Dictionary d is generated using some function generate_dict() and may have the following keys: 'x', 'y' and 'z', but you cannot be sure which of them are present in a given dictionary.  You want to assign value of key 'x' to attribute 'a', 'y' to attribute 'b' etc. In such case, you have to surround each assignment with try-catch, like this:

```
o = Object()
d = generate_dict()
try:
    o.a = d['x']
except:
    pass
try:
    o.b = d['y']
except:
    pass
```

etc. You may also replace try-excepts with checking if a given key exists in the dictionary, but the problem is still there. What happens, if you have dozens of key-attribute mappings? The number of lines grows quickly.

Another way to code this is to generate two tables of attribute and key names and execute the code in a loop using exec function, like this:

```
o = Object()
d = generate_dict()

attributeNames = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dataDictKeys = ['x', 'y', 'z']
for (attr, key) in zip(attributeNames, dataDictKeys):
    try:
        exec("o.{attr} = d['{key}']".format(attr = attr, key = key))
    except:
        pass
```

While this is not a good coding practice to do such things, still this somehow may solve your problem. But use it with caution.